# Годы or годах for "in a decade"

Tags: грамматика, падежи, склонение

When referring to an event in a specific year, it is *в этом году* with *этом* replaced by the year in prepositional, e. g., *в 1956-м году*. But for decades I have seen both *в 1950-х годах* and *в 1950-е годы*. What is the difference in usage between these two choices?

Comment: Very good question. I do not feel any semantic difference between accusative _годы_ and locative _годах_ here, but the latter is more common.

Comment: Rosenthal [confirms](http://upravlenie.academic.ru/120/%D0%B2_%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%85) that: ‘В двадцатых годах (реже в двадцатые годы) нашего века (при обозначении десятилетий посредством порядковых числительных чаще употребляется не вин. падеж, а предл.)’.

Comment: And please pay attention to correct spelling of abbreviation of inflection: _1950-х_, not _1950ых_ as it was written before my edit.

Comment: That в этих годах and в эти годы are the same thing nevertheless seems strange. Are there other examples where an accusative and prepositional case for describing time are equivalent?

Comment: With other units of time at least: _в пятнадцатый — шестнадцатый века нашей эры_ (acc.) and _в пятнадцатом — шестнадцатом веках нашей эры_ (loc.). I in person would not say it in the first way, but you can hear it sometimes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For me there is no any difference between locative *в пятидеся́тых года́х* and accusative *в пятидеся́тые го́ды*, neither semantic, nor stylistic, nor dialectical. But in literary Russian the former variant seems to prevail.

> В двадцатых годах (реже в двадцатые годы) нашего века (при обозначении десятилетий посредством порядковых числительных чаще употребляется не вин. падеж, а предл.).

— Д. Э. Розенталь. Пунктуация и управление в русском языке.

You’ve asked is it about *год* only. No, in my Russian units of time with ordinals may be declined to answer *когда?* question in this way:

> в первые секунды
>   в первые минуты
>   в первые часы
>   в первые дни
>   в первые недели / на первых неделях
>   в первые месяцы / в первых месяцах / на первых месяцах
>   в первые годы / в первых годах
>   в первые десятилетия / в первых десятилетиях
>   в первые века / в первых веках
>   на первых порах
>   в первые мгновения

But I cannot see any system here.

Comment: `на первых неделях` and `на первых месяцах` do not sound right to me

Comment: How about classic "Во первых строках моего письма...."? This could extend the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

These two choices are equivalent, but I would say the *"в пятидесятых годах"* form is a bit more frequently used than *"в пятидесятые годы"*.